# Getting objects "value" in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am creating a blackjack game where my deck consists of objects(cardname: value) within an array.

I am wondering if there is a function for javascript objects where I can get an objects value (in my case, the numeric score each card is worth) without having to name the key (ex: "aced")?

Please refer to my code below, specifically in the for loop; I don't know what to replace "myHand[card[value]]" with.

Thanks

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length, t, i;
  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (m) {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }
  return array;
}

var deck = [{"aced": 11}, {"twod": 2}, {"threed": 3}, {"fourd": 4}, {"fived": 5}, {"sixd":6}, {"sevend": 7}, {"eightd": 8}, {"nined": 9}, {"tend": 10}, {"jackd": 10}, {"queend": 10}, {"kingd": 10},
{"acec": 11}, {"twoc": 2}, {"threec": 3}, {"fourc": 4}, {"fivec": 5}, {"sixc":6}, {"sevenc": 7}, {"eightc": 8}, {"ninec": 9}, {"tenc": 10}, {"jackc": 10}, {"queenc": 10}, {"kingc": 10},
{"aceh": 11}, {"twoh": 2}, {"threeh": 3}, {"fourh": 4}, {"fiveh": 5}, {"sixh":6}, {"sevenh": 7}, {"eighth": 8}, {"nineh": 9}, {"tenh": 10}, {"jackh": 10}, {"queenh": 10}, {"kingh": 10},
{"aces": 11}, {"twos": 2}, {"threes": 3}, {"fours": 4}, {"fives": 5}, {"sixs":6}, {"sevens": 7}, {"eights": 8}, {"nines": 9}, {"tens": 10}, {"jacks": 10}, {"queens": 10}, {"kings": 10}];

shuffle(deck);

function userHand() {
    var myHand = [deck.pop(), deck.pop()];
}

function countScore(myHand) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var card in myHand) {
        total += myHand[card[value]];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want keys, why not make it a simple array?

Comment: If you don't know what they keys will be, then you shouldn't be using key/value pairs. Use Arrays, like `["aced", 11]`. Then you can use numeric indices. Or make your objects more complex, like `{card:"aced",value:11}`

Comment: It'd be much easier if you had a better card data model, like `{ card: "aced", value: 11 }`

Comment: actually now that you mention it, an array within an array seems more logical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could potentially change your array, if you're not too far in to this. so rather than having each card be

```
{'name': value}
```

you could have each card be

```
{'type': name, 'value': number}
```

for instance, to have a 3 of hearts:

```
{'type': threeh, 'value': 3}.
```

then, you could access the value by

```
myHand[card.value]
```

and the name by

```
myHand[card.type]
```